Is there a way to change the hover options in wordpress 6.6.1
I am new to wordpress and I am trying to change the hover styling but I am unable to find the settings. The hover is a hyperlink in the header menu.
Using the online editor, appearance, edit. I selected the navigation block. I then looked under the settings and styles but I could not find a setting for hovering. The closest thing I saw was custom css, but I have no idea how to use that function 

There might not be an option for that from the UI, it will depend on which theme your WordPress is using.
In that case, you will need to use custom CSS. You should check what classes the menu elements have and apply the styles you want.
For example, the menu items could have this class: menu-item, so in that case you need to add a CSS rule like this:
.menu-item:hover {
    color: blue; 
}

